# Display collection of same type in TreeView

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I want to display following structure

```
Duplication
    DuplicateLine1
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
         MORE OCCURENCES in OTHER COMPONENTS
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
    DuplicateLine2
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
         MORE OCCURENCES in OTHER COMPONENTS
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
           filename_startline_endline
```

This is my DataStructure

```
public class CloneBlock
{
    public string DuplicateLine;
    public List<Occurrence> Occurrences { get; set; }
    public List<Occurrence> OtherOccurrences { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I have two same type of collections in one class.
I am trying to display it using HierarchialDataTemplate but with NO success.

The problem is only one of the collection can be displayed as the type is same.

XAML:

```
        <Grid.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CloneBlock}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Occurrences}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Background='AliceBlue' Text='{Binding CloneDisplayline}' />
                    <TextBlock Background='Aqua' FontSize="12" Width="20" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text='{Binding OccurrenceCount}' />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
                    DataType="{x:Type local:Occurrence}">
                <TextBlock Text='{Binding FileId}' />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Duplication" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding CloneBlocks}">
```

Any ideas?? How to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try CompositeCollection.

Comment: Is `MORE OCCURENCES in OTHER COMPONENTS` meant to indicate an additional tree item, or is it just commentary?

Comment: Yes, it's an additional tree Item

Comment: Is it a child of Duplication or of DuplicateLine1? Is it a sibling of the filename_startline_endline lines preceding it?

Comment: MORE OCCURENCES in OTHER COMPONENTS is a Header and the list under it is of the same type as of the list above.

Comment: What is the parent of **MORE OCCURENCES in OTHER COMPONENTS**? Tell me the name of the parent of **MORE OCCURENCES in OTHER COMPONENTS** or I can't help you.